# Redis lua script - check redis.call('JSON.SET') result

Tags: redis, lua, stackexchange.redis

I'm using lua scripting with Redis, using Redis StackExchange library.
What I want to accomplish, is to check the result of the execution of JSON.SET, and then return 1 in case it was succesfull, 0 otherwise

When I execute the following script, I get as result 0

```
var result = await db.ScriptEvaluateAsync(@"local res = redis.call('JSON.SET', KEYS[1], '$', ARGV[1]) if (res == 'OK') then return 1 else return 0 end",
                new[] { new RedisKey(person.Id.ToString()) },
                new[] { new RedisValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(person)));
```

but if I change it in this way, then I get as result: OK

```
var result = await db.ScriptEvaluateAsync(@"local res = redis.call('JSON.SET', KEYS[1], '$', ARGV[1]) if (res == 'OK') then return 1 else return res end",
                new[] { new RedisKey(person.Id.ToString()) },
                new[] { new RedisValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(person)));
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Redis Lua API documentation](https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/lua-api/#resp2-to-lua-type-conversion) has provides this helpful tidbit:

> ### RESP2 to Lua type conversion
>
> ...
>
> - RESP2 status reply -> Lua table with a single ok field containing the status string

This means that an `OK` reply is actually a Lua table, that has a single `ok` key with the value of "OK". Therefore, a "right" way to check it would be:

```lua
if res["ok"] ~= nil then
  return 1
else
  return 0
end
```

Also, because Redis will convert a returned Lua Boolean to an integer, you can just do:

```lua
return res["ok"] ~= nil
```